# Turtle from image won't draw over another turtle's stamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

This code sets up a background of stamps placed by one turtle. Another turtle, (whose shape is from an imported image file) moves around over the background. But the second turtle is not visible whenever it is positioned over a stamp placed by the first turtle. If I make the moving turtle one of the standard shapes, eg circle, then it stays visible. So there's something odd about using an imported image for the turtle, which causes it to disappear whenever it's on top of one of the stamps.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from turtle import *
from time import sleep

scr = Screen()

scr.register_shape('player.gif')

mover = Turtle()
bgnd = Turtle()

bgnd.color('blue')

mover.shape('player.gif')
bgnd.shape('square')

for i in range(5):
    bgnd.goto(i*20,0)
    bgnd.stamp()

for i in range(5):
    mover.goto((8-i)*20,0)
    sleep(1)
```

The accompanying image is the one I've referred to as player.gif (I can see it at the bottom of the post, but it's very small).

Can anyone help explain why this is and how to get around it?

[image: player.gif]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or subtlety, but stamps aren't pixels on the screen like `dot()` -- the `stamp()` function returns an ID that allows selectively removing them.  My guess is it's a layering issue with the underlying tkinter.  In turtle, if you have a layering issue, sometimes it helps to do things in a different order:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from time import sleep

background = Turtle()
background.hideturtle()
background.color('blue')
background.shape('square')

for i in range(5):
    background.goto(i * 20, 0)
    background.stamp()

screen = Screen()
screen.register_shape('player.gif')

mover = Turtle()
mover.shape('player.gif')

for i in range(5):
    mover.goto((8 - i) * 20, 0)
    sleep(1)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

In the long run, `time.sleep()` isn't a friend of event-based turtle.  It's fine for examples like this but anything more and it will cause more problems than it solves.  Look into the `ontimer()` method of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for this - I tried various versions of reordering my code to see the effect, and it only worked where everything for the background turtle was implemented before I even created the mover turtle. \nThanks also for the tip about screen.ontimer().